# Ionic 3 - set id value in alert controller

Tags: typescript, ionic3

Is it possible to set the `id` value in alert controller in ionic 3?

Normally in html tags we can set the `id` value. But here while display alert dialog, we are using alert controller in ts code. So is there any way to set `id` in the alert controller?

Answer (score 0):

try below example and check documentation [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/alert/AlertController/)

```
import { AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';

constructor(private alertCtrl: AlertController) {

}

presentAlert() {
  let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
    title: 'Low battery',
    subTitle: '10% of battery remaining',
    buttons: ['Dismiss']
  });
  alert.present();
}

presentConfirm() {
  let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
    title: 'Confirm purchase',
    message: 'Do you want to buy this book?',
    buttons: [
      {
        text: 'Cancel',
        role: 'cancel',
        handler: () => {
          console.log('Cancel clicked');
        }
      },
      {
        text: 'Buy',
        handler: () => {
          console.log('Buy clicked');
        }
      }
    ]
  });
  alert.present();
}

presentPrompt() {
  let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
    title: 'Login',
    inputs: [
      {
        name: 'username',
        placeholder: 'Username'
      },
      {
        name: 'password',
        placeholder: 'Password',
        type: 'password'
      }
    ],
    buttons: [
      {
        text: 'Cancel',
        role: 'cancel',
        handler: data => {
          console.log('Cancel clicked');
        }
      },
      {
        text: 'Login',
        handler: data => {
          if (User.isValid(data.username, data.password)) {
            // logged in!
          } else {
            // invalid login
            return false;
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  });
  alert.present();
}
```

Comment: here where we are setting id for alert controller and their buttons. Like  **id="mainalert"**   and for buttons **id="cancelBtn" & id="buyBtn"** etc. I knew that below code is not possible. But is it anyway to achieve this.  

 `let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
    title: 'Low battery',
    subTitle: '10% of battery remaining',
    id: 'alertCtrl',
    buttons: [
      {
        text: 'Cancel',
 id: 'cancelBtn',
        role: 'cancel',
        handler: data => {
          console.log('Cancel clicked');
        }
      }
  });
  alert.present();`

Comment: anybody have any idea about this issue?